# Panic while rmmod

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Hello I am newbie in kernel dev,

Created a simple program:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");


int messager(void*);
struct task_struct* kthrstr;

static int start_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading the messager\n");

    kthrstr = kthread_create(messager,NULL,"MESSAGER");
    wake_up_process(kthrstr);
    return 0;
}

static void stop_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading the messager\n");
    kthread_stop(kthrstr);
}

int messager(void* varg)
{
    daemonize("MESSAGER");
    allow_signal(SIGKILL);

    while(1)
    {   
        printk(KERN_INFO "Timeout: Hello");
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        schedule_timeout(10 * HZ);
        if (signal_pending(current))
            break;  
    }
    return 0;
} 

module_init(start_module);
module_exit(stop_module);
```

The module gets loaded properly and the messages too appear in syslog as expected. But when the module is unloaded using rmmod, it panics as shown below. Please help me in identifying as what wrong is happening and how to rectify:

```
[ 2207.466086] Timeout: Hello
[ 2215.756784] Unloading the messager
[ 2217.461846] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at f0ca8054
[ 2217.462328] IP: [<f0ca8054>] 0xf0ca8054
[ 2217.462772] *pdpt = 0000000000a76001 *pde = 000000002f8b1067 *pte = 0000000000000000 
[ 2217.463003] Oops: 0010 [#1] PREEMPT SMP 
[ 2217.463065] last sysfs file: /sys/module/ip6_tables/initstate
[ 2217.463328] Modules linked in: fuse ip6t_LOG xt_tcpudp xt_pkttype ipt_LOG xt_limit vmsync vmblock af_packet mperf snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq edd ip6t_REJECT nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ip6table_raw xt_NOTRACK ipt_REJECT iptable_raw iptable_filter ip6table_mangle nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_tables xt_conntrack nf_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables x_tables snd_ens1371 gameport snd_rawmidi snd_seq_device snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm sg snd_timer ppdev pcnet32 mptctl snd sr_mod soundcore vmci pcspkr cdrom parport_pc vmxnet shpchp snd_page_alloc parport i2c_piix4 vmw_balloon pci_hotplug floppy button ac container ext4 jbd2 crc16 linear dm_snapshot dm_mod fan processor thermal thermal_sys ata_generic mptspi mptscsih mptbase scsi_transport_spi [last unloaded: printmsg]
[ 2217.463839] 
[ 2217.463957] Pid: 6684, comm: MESSAGER Not tainted 2.6.37.1-1.2-desktop #1 VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform
[ 2217.464156] EIP: 0060:[<f0ca8054>] EFLAGS: 00010296 CPU: 0
[ 2217.464216] EIP is at 0xf0ca8054
[ 2217.464249] EAX: 00000000 EBX: e8678430 ECX: 00000286 EDX: 00000000
[ 2217.464275] ESI: 00000000 EDI: f0ca8000 EBP: 00000000 ESP: eccedfb4
[ 2217.464302]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 0000 SS: 0068
[ 2217.464414] Process MESSAGER (pid: 6684, ti=eccec000 task=e8678430 task.ti=eccec000)
[ 2217.464450] Stack:
[ 2217.464580]  f0ca80f9 00000000 ec52ff2c c0265dc4 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000101
[ 2217.464714]  eccedfd4 eccedfd4 00000000 c0265d50 ec52ff2c c02034e6 00000000 00000000
[ 2217.464734]  00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 2217.464787] Call Trace:
[ 2217.465094] Inexact backtrace:
[ 2217.465097] 
[ 2217.476943]  [<c0265dc4>] ? kthread+0x74/0x80
[ 2217.476965]  [<c0265d50>] ? kthread+0x0/0x80
[ 2217.476985]  [<c02034e6>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
[ 2217.483598] Code:  Bad EIP value.
[ 2217.483786] EIP: [<f0ca8054>] 0xf0ca8054 SS:ESP 0068:eccedfb4
[ 2217.483849] CR2: 00000000f0ca8054
[ 2217.484325] ---[ end trace dc9382a06b455776 ]---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module is crashing because the call to `daemonize()` causes the later `kthread_stop()` call to return without waiting.

Additionally, as noted [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/118935/), `kthread_stop()` does not send a signal to the thread, but rather makes `kthread_should_stop()` return true. in short, change your code to loop on `while (!kthread_should_stop())`, and remove the `daemonize` (unneeded and dangerous here) and `allow_signal` calls.

Comment: Wouldn't that just result in an infinite loop rather than an oops?

Comment: @bdonlan: Yes, it would. It appears the actual problem is the `daemonize` call, `daemonize` calls `exit_mm`, which calls `mm_release`, which signals `vfork_done`, making `kthread_stop` believe the thread to have ended. this makes `kthread_stop` return instead of waiting, causing the crash.

Comment: The moral of the story is, either use `kernel_thread` and `daemonize`, or use `kthread_create`/`kthread_run`. doing both at the same time is bound to hurt you.

Comment: @Hasturkun: Thanks a lot! It worked. I have one more question: Why you say to remove 'allow_signal' call. What if I need to catch a signal?

Comment: @Albert: I suggested removing it only because it wasn't needed in this case. You may use `allow_signal` if you need to catch a signal, just be aware that `kthread_stop()` will not deliver one to you.

Comment: Thanks Hasturkun for your help!

Comment: @Hasturkun: So that means if I need to handle signals inside a thread, I would have to use 'kernel_thread' and 'daemonize' calls instead of Kthread facility?

Comment: @Albert: No, it does not. `allow_signal` can be used in both cases, it does not require you to use `daemonize`